# I've got a theme I can't update and won't let go

Tags: themes, database

I created a custom theme for a client a while back and then it sorta mysteriously broke several months later by reverting to an early version that had a few links to my website hard coded into it. I made the fixes but then discovered that no matter how I tried to make the changes - ftp'ing up the file, fixing from right within wordpress, etc. - wordpress just went right back to the version that was currently up there. I even added random text to check my theory and that wouldn't show up either. Yet, oddly enough, I could go into the theme editor in Wordpress and see the correct version of the file showing up.

I finally decided to just switch to another theme, nuke that one and try to fix it and upload it again. Wordpress won't let me switch to another theme. I'll pick another theme and activate it, the website will completely stop showing up, and I'll go back to the Theme editor and the original theme will be appearing as the default theme. At this point, I'm a little afraid to remove the template.

I'm wondering if this is some type of database issue. However, my client's control panel does not give her access to the database. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: If you [enable `WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) you can see the errors that prevent the page from showing.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be:

1. Overwrite with clean copy of WordPress.
2. Try to output path constants and verify that theme is loaded from proper directory.
3. Try disabling all plugins.
4. Install configuration check plugin, like [ServerBuddy](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/serverbuddy-by-pluginbuddy/), and see f anything lights up as horribly broken.

Comment: According to ServerBuddy, the following items are at FAIL:
MYSql Version 4.1.22-standard-log
Allow Call Time Pass Reference On
Maximum Execution Time (secs) 30
Maximum Input Time (secs) -1
Register Globals On

I'm concerned about the SQL version - she's running wordpress 3.0.04. Could that be the showstopper?

Comment: @Katy Jackson [hosting requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress) are MySQL _4.1.2 or greater_ so it seems marginally ok (but starting with 3.2 WP will require _5.0.15 or greater_).